# MySql correct connect in command line, but not connect remote

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a problem. In Oracle Linux Server 7.6 with MySQL 8.0.17.
In command line I have correct connection to database

[image]

In this user I have all needed privileges
[image]

In my.cnf I enabled remote access
[image]

[image]

But if I try to connect remote HeidiSql error
[image]

And local server phpMyAdmin too (Can't connect to mysql server)
[image]

SSH tunnel connect also wrong (USING PASSWORD YES).

**But password is correct**! Please help. What am I doing wrong or how to resolve this problem and remote connect to MySQL?

Comment: Your user has the privileges on localhost, but not on dmw0717.detmir-group.ru. Fix your user.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mark Rotteveel
Need to add user user@host